# C auto return type

Tags: c, return-type

This may be a stupid question but I was going through the K&R book to practice C a bit noticed that you don't need to specify a return type for the functions. I thought C was a strongly typed language. How is this possible ? Is this something like type inference ? Maybe they let something like this because of implicit conversion but a bit confused to see this..

Eg:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = funct();
}

funct()
{
    return 3;
}
```

Comment: The "implicit `int`" is generally considered a bad practice.  Don't use it.

Comment: And guess what, even if you declared funct as a function returning a char, you would have no problem with assigning it to an int variable because it is prototyped AFTER its use.  
What you should do is prototyping funct in a header file (.h) and #include it at the top of your source file (.c) just after system includes and library includes (in this order)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing that fancy; the default return type is int.

Comment: Only in C89. In C99 "default int" has been removed.

Answer (score 3):

If the return type is omitted, it defaults to `int`.

So `funct()` returns a type `int`. That's why the code compiles.

This is depreciated though, modern compilers will warn you if you omit the return type. (It is not allowed at all in C99 and C++.)

**EDIT :**
In addition to that, in your example, you don't declare the `funct()` function before you call it.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype#Uses):

> In C, if a function is not previously declared and its name occurs in
>   an expression followed by a left parenthesis, it is implicitly
>   declared as a function that returns an int and nothing is assumed
>   about its arguments.

Answer (score 3):

C89 had an implicit `int` rule when the type specifier was omitted (for example the return type of a function).

C99 no longer allows a type specifier type to be omitted.

As you quote K&R2, the book explicitly explained it (in 4.1 Basic functions):

> If the return type is omitted, int is assumed

Answer (score 2):

Well actually this is (afaik) non standard in C99 (but was allowed in C89 - see comments), but most compilers **assume** a return type of **int** if none is specified. However, any decent compiler should put out a warning about this and you always should take warnings seriously.

Comment: It's not non-standard, C89 allowed it, but C99 doesn't.

Comment: Edited my answer - but if C99 doesn't allow it, it is actually non-standard, isn't it?

Comment: Yes and no; C99 isn't as widely adopted as C89, so it's only "non-standard" if you chose to adopt C99. If you want to continue to use the older C89 standard you can (some compilers for programmable microchips are C89-only).

Comment: Also, from memory, GCC would allow implicit int even in C99 mode, but would warn about it. I think you have to switch on `-pedantic` to get it to warn too.

Comment: Yeah well any compiler I know of does allow it - but they issue a warning about it. I quickly scanned my copy of c99 and didn't find anything about unspecified return types defaulting to int, thus my answer. But it seems to be very common as I'm always biting my students heads of when they write stuff like "main() {...}" - it is (imo) probably the best communicating that it is in fact non-standard as of todays C standard ;) (however, as you can see, the simple answer just won and I will continue fighting my students *g*)

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of C, function return types and arguments without types would default to `int` if there was no type specified, although this has been removed from C99 onwards, where functions *must* be declared and defined with a return type, and arguments *must* be specified with a type.